# noremap not working in modeline

Tags: key-bindings, modeline

For a specific file I need some dedicate configurations.

So, I put this in the top of the file:

```
% vim: noremap a <ESC>l<ESC>
```

I get the following error message:

```
"test" 2L, 30B
Error detected while processing modelines:
line    1:
E518: Unknown option: a
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

So, how can I force remap command for specific file in the `vim:` preamble mechanism?

Comment: There is no "remap command".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You are probably thinking of [modelines](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#modeline), but those allow you to only specify specific options when starting to edit that particular file (and only if the [modeline](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27modeline%27) and [modelineexpr](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27modelineexpr%27) options are set and even then not only all options, since those could be considered a security risk).

But in any case, it only allows you to set some specific options and nothing more. You cannot create autocommands, map keys or run ex commands. If you really want that, you would need to create a BufEnter autocommand (e.g. in your vimrc file) and specify your mapping there. (Make sure to use buffer-local options and mappings in any case).